# mongodb - using $geoNear gives "geo near accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point" when using maxDistance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson, geonear

This appears to be a common error but I can't seem to make it work with all the suggestions I've seen. This is my setup:

```
// point.js (based on mongoose recommended subdocument pattern for reusing the GeoJSON definition
// see here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/geojson.html)
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const pointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Point'],
        required: true
    },
    coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        required: true,
    }
});

exports = pointSchema;
```

```
// user.js
var schema = new Schema({
  location: {
    type: pointSchema,
  },
  ...
});

schema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });
var User = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

```
// routeHandler.js
          const near = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [lng, lat] };
          User.aggregate([
            { $geoNear: {
              near,
              distanceField: 'dist',
              maxDistance: 100000,
              spherical: true,
            } },
            ...
          ]).exec((err, results) => {
            console.log('error or results:', err, results);
          });
```

And I get this error:

> MongoError: Failed to determine whether query system can provide a covered projection :: caused by :: geo near
> accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $maxDistance: 100000.0

Most of the threads I've seen suggest that it's an issue with indexing, but you can see in `user.js` that I'm directly calling

```
schema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });
```

without any luck.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had same issue and went through many many solutions but any of them didn't work as the
**real issue was in data**.

In My Model had 2dsphere index which was correct but when using 2dshpere **the location in the database should be in format of location : [ lng, lat ] which was the main issue.** as mongodb does not validate location array this format.

Verify both the data in DB and points specified while querying both should be correct format.

*Hope it helps someone!*

Comment: Yep that's true. In my case the problem was that I supplied the coordinates as strings instead of numbers.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the same error and after researching a lot I found that which running the aggregation query. I was passing the coordinates as array of string which should be an array of Number.

```
{
        $geoNear: {
          near: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [103.83797, 1.46103],
          },
          distanceField: "dist.calculated",
          maxDistance: distance,
          includeLocs: "dist.location",
          spherical: true,
        },
      },
```

Answer (score 2):

```
issue :  caused by :: geo near accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $maxDistance: 1000.0

Solution : i got this issue because i passed latitude and longitude in string format through postman, and directly passed into query parameter, SO i changed it into number and it's resolved.

    searchData = await ServiceIndividualModel.aggregate([{
                    $geoNear: {
                        near: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [Number(longitude), Number(latitude)]
                        },
                       distanceField: "distance",
                       maxDistance: 1000,
                       spherical: true
                    }   
                }])
```

Answer (score 0):

the postman will conver the number to string,add this
$geoNear: {
near: {
type: "Point",
coordinates: [Number(longitude), Number(latitude)]
},

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).